# Moblie Menu Design like picture. No idea where to start

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw a cool design of the mobile menu.com

I don't understand where to even begin to make something like this.

http://weedmaps.com/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdEz8.jpg

Comment: Maybe OP should provide a warning that the site contains adult content before linking to it...

Comment: There is a two menu. Which one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul` to list your menu, than add some icons next to labels.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .3);
}

li span {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></span>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-bookmark fa-fw"></span>Deals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-car fa-fw"></span>Deliveries</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created your navigation links and placed them behind the web page. Using JQuery we move the page left and down to show the navigation. Then reversing that to close it. Hope it helps!

```js
$("a#menuOff").hide(0);

$( "a#menuOn" ).click(function() {
 var tog = "10%" 
  $(".page").animate({left: tog});  
  $(".page").animate({top: tog});
  $("a#menuOn").hide();  
  $("a#menuOff").show();
  $(".page").css("width","90%");
});

$( "a#menuOff" ).click(function() {
 var tog = "0%" 
  $(".page").animate({left: tog}); 
  $(".page").animate({top: tog});
  $("a#menuOff").hide();  
  $("a#menuOn").show();
  $(".page").css("width","100%");
});
```

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#navbar {
 height:100vh;
 color:#fff;
 background:#212121;
}
.page {
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index:1000;
 top:0;
 margin-left:0;
 font-family:Arial;
}
#reveal {
/*  width:90%!important;
 margin-left:10%!important; */
}
.page nav {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0 1em;
 line-height:1.5em;
 background:#ccc;
}
.page nav a {
 color:red;
}
.page h1 {
 text-align:center;
 background:#fafafa;
 line-height:2em;
 border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
 font-size:1.8em;
}
.page p {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:#fafafa;
 padding:1em;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 </ul>
 
 <div class="page" id="reveal">
  <header>
   <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menuOn">Menu</a>          <a href="#" id="menuOff">Menu</a>

   </nav>
   <h1>Your Title</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, sit dolores accusamus corporis fugiat error soluta! Et consectetur vel deleniti enim repellendus, eveniet veniam, voluptatem unde iure, debitis corporis praesentium? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam voluptates, ab dignissimos eum porro laborum deleniti temporibus sed corrupti dolor voluptatem molestiae possimus quis, tenetur adipisci animi labore fuga mollitia.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam suscipit quibusdam laboriosam impedit, velit laudantium eligendi deleniti! In, molestiae aliquid expedita explicabo minima tenetur quod, totam dolores nesciunt, dignissimos debitis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit nesciunt nostrum dolor modi! Ipsum culpa ab temporibus qui, modi tenetur, vitae, maiores ipsam doloribus reprehenderit ducimus aspernatur minima officiis iure.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, sit dolores accusamus corporis fugiat error soluta! Et consectetur vel deleniti enim repellendus, eveniet veniam, voluptatem unde iure, debitis corporis praesentium? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam voluptates, ab dignissimos eum porro laborum deleniti temporibus sed corrupti dolor voluptatem molestiae possimus quis, tenetur adipisci animi labore fuga mollitia.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam suscipit quibusdam laboriosam impedit, velit laudantium eligendi deleniti! In, molestiae aliquid expedita explicabo minima tenetur quod, totam dolores nesciunt, dignissimos debitis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit nesciunt nostrum dolor modi! Ipsum culpa ab temporibus qui, modi tenetur, vitae, maiores ipsam doloribus reprehenderit ducimus aspernatur minima officiis iure.</p>
  </article>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) for this.

Ionic has cli support which will automatically create a template with menu.You can then customize as much as you like after that. Ionic cli command for that is:

```
ionic start yourAppName sidemenu
```